# AttributeError: module Django.contrib.auth.views has no attributes

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, attributeerror

I am new to the django development.
In my Django app useraccounts, I am creating blog site. However, when I went to run python manage.py makemigrations, I encounter the error: AttributeError: module Django.contrib.auth.views has no attribute 'login'.
Don't know what to do .

Here is my code:

model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def approve_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
        # kwargs--handle named arguments that you have not defined in advance.
        #reverse()--if you change the url in future then you can reference that url using reverse(urlname).
        #This looks through all URLs defined in your project for the URL defined with the name url_name and returns the actual URL

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post',related_name='comments',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_list")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from blog_app.models import Post, Comment
from django.utils import timezone
from blog_app.form import PostForm, CommentForm

from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                  DetailView,CreateView,
                                  UpdateView,DeleteView)

from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'about.html'

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post


class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'

    form_class = PostForm

    model = Post


class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'

    form_class = PostForm

    model = Post


class DraftListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_list.html'

    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=True).order_by('created_date')


class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('post_list')

#######################################
## Functions that require a pk match ##
#######################################

@login_required
def post_publish(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.publish()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=pk)

@login_required
def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/comment_form.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def comment_approve(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    comment.approve()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=comment.post.pk)


@login_required
def comment_remove(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    post_pk = comment.post.pk
    comment.delete()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=post_pk)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog_app.urls')),
    path('accounts/login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('accounts/logout/', views.logout, name='logout', kwargs={'next_page': '/'}),
]
```

Terminal

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\vinee\Desktop\WEB- D\Projects\Blog\Blog\urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path('accounts/login/', views.login, name='login'),
AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'login'
```

Answer (score 0):

[contrib.auth.views.login(), logout() were deprecated in Django 2.1.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#features-removed-in-2-1)

You can make some changes in your urls.py file:

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog_app.urls')),
    path('accounts/login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('accounts/logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout', kwargs={'next_page': '/'}),
]
```

Also, when you specify the **login_url** parameter `login_url = '/login/'` in your views.py, are you expecting another login page with the path '/login'? Because in your urls.py, your login page path is 'accounts/login/'.

Also, please refer to the latest Django docs for further information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users